# Prove that $\triangledown\times\left[\frac 1r(A\times R)\right]=\frac 1rA+\frac{A\cdot R}{r^3}R$ for any constant vector $A$.

Tags: vectors, proof-explanation, inner-products, cross-product

**Question :** Prove that $$\triangledown\times\left[\frac 1r(A\times R)\right]=\frac 1rA+\frac{A\cdot R}{r^3}R$$ for any constant vector $A$.

---

**Proof**

[image]

---

**Doubt :** I don't know how we split the term into two terms in the first line. I understand the first term, but not the second.

---

Comment: Its just the product rule of differentiation applied to the multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we can use an simpler example to illustrate this, consider a vector field $U:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ and a scalar field $g:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$.

Then we compute its curl. We can use the index formula for curl
$$
\nabla\times(gU)=\sum_{ijk}\epsilon_{ijk} e_i\partial_j (g U_k)\\
=\sum_{ijk}\epsilon_{ijk} e_i[(\partial_j g) U_k+g(\partial_j U_k)]\\
=(\nabla g)\times U+g\nabla\times U
$$
Then use the Leibniz rule to separate it into two terms, and represent it back in terms of outer product.

In your first line, substitute $g=\frac 1r$, $U=A\times R$, then you get your 2 terms